# Using DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance().format(date);

Tags: java, junit, timezone, environment

When running some tests I came across the following issue. When using:

```
private String printStandardDate(Date date) {
    return DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance(
        DateFormat.SHORT, DateFormat.SHORT).format(date);
}
```

I found this produced different formats of Date depending on the location the tests where run from. So locally in windows / eclipse I got a result: 04/02/12 18:18 but on the Linux box in America I get 2/4/12 6:18 PM

This causes my Tests/Build to fail:

> expected:<[04/02/12 18:18]> but was:<[2/4/12 6:18 PM]>

Could anyone explain this behavior?

Comment: You did not give the TimeZone on each server

Comment: Sorry I am in GMT timezone and Linux box is EST

Answer (score 20, accepted):

That's not strange, that's exactly how it's supposed to work.

The API documentation of `DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance` says:

> Gets the date/time formatter with the given date and time formatting styles **for the default locale.**

The default locale is different on your Windows system than on the Linux box in America.

If you want exact control over the date and time format, use `SimpleDateFormat` and specify the format yourself. For example:

```
private String printStandardDate(Date date) {
    return new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yy HH:mm").format(date);
}
```

Even better would be to re-use the `SimpleDateFormat` object, but beware that it is not thread-safe (if the method might be called from multiple threads at the same time, things will get messed up if those threads use the same `SimpleDateFormat` object).

```
private static final DateFormat DATE_FORMAT =
    new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yy HH:mm");

private String printStandardDate(Date date) {
    return DATE_FORMAT.format(date);
}
```

Comment: @ShouhengWang No, class `SimpleDateFormat` is not thread-safe. My answer above is from 2012 - nowadays it's better to use the new Java date and time API that was added in Java 8. The formatters in the package `java.time.format` are thread-safe.

Answer (score 11):

The format is based on the default locale in your code. If you want to ensure results you must make sure to use a specific locale. The `getDateTimeInstance` method is overloaded to offer an [alternative method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#getDateTimeInstance%28int,%20int,%20java.util.Locale%29) that receives the locale that you want to use as parameter.

```
public static final DateFormat getDateTimeInstance(int dateStyle,
                             int timeStyle,
                             Locale aLocale)
```

If you use the same locale in both testing environments, the result should be the same.

Comment: actually they shouldn't, since `TimeZone.getDefault()` plays a role as well, so that needs to be set too. This is a good answer nonetheless.