# java android DateFormat ignores modified locale settings

Tags: java, android, date, date-format, simpledateformat

In my app for displaying the date I use the following code:

```
public static String format (Date date) {
    DateFormat formater = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance(DateFormat.SHORT,DateFormat.SHORT);
    return formater.format(date);
}
```

In my Android device as default regional date format I have `"Regional (31.10.2013)"` and then my app works as expected.

However I can change in my Android settings date format to ex. `"2013.10.31"` and then unfortunately my app seems to ignore those settings and still display date in default format `"31.10.2013"`. Why? How to format date to take into consideration those Android settings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works correctly as you are using `DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance`. 
According to the API [doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#getDateInstance%28int,%20java.util.Locale%29)-

> Gets the date/time formatter with the given date and time formatting styles for **the default locale**.

For your case, it's better to use `SimpleDateFormat` and specify the format yourself. For example:

```
private String printStandardDate(Date date) {
    return new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yy").format(date);
}
```

You can check this so -[Using DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance().format(date);](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11312901/using-dateformat-getdatetimeinstance-formatdate)

UPDATE: can you please check this-

```
public static String format (Date date) {
  DateFormat dateFormat = 
         android.text.format.DateFormat.getDateFormat(getApplicationContext());
    return dateFormat.format(date);
}
```

Comment: Sorry man, I don't want to set the fixed date format. I would to apply the format which Android user set in the device settings. Thus any fixed format "dd/MM/yy" cannot be taken into consideration.

Comment: And why do you think I don't use getDateTimeInstance according to the doc? I use it according to the doc (at least in my understanding) and I don't want to apply any fixed locale as I want to use the one set in Android device settings).

Comment: Finally it works as expected, thank you. But I will never understand Android philosophy... (Btw, you made a small error return dateFormat.format(date)).